# Mercurial revset selecting up to a bookmark

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-revsets

If I have this changesets in my repository

```
A --> B --> C --> D
      *
```

B is bookmarked and D is at the tip - how do I create a revset that will select everything between B and D but not B.

Specifically I'm trying to squash C and D in to B, something like :

```
hg strip -r "bookmark:." -k
```

except this line will also delete the commit B which I want to keep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear whether you want to squash C and D, creating a new commit C', or whether you want to squash B, C, and D, creating a new commit B', which will keep the original bookmark.

For the first:

```
hg rebase -s 'children(bookmark)' -d bookmark --collapse -m <msg>
```

You need to specify a commit message with either the `-m` or the `-l` option, or you'll get dropped into the editor.

For the second:

```
hg rebase -s bookmark -d bookmark^ --collapse -m <msg>
```

For a revset to specify all descendants of a revision, excluding the revision itself, use the following revset:

```
children(bookmark)::
```

Note that a non-linear history at this point can create unexpected results (in particular, the use of `children()` here assumes only a single child revision).

Remember to enable the rebase extension in your hgrc file for this.

Comment: >Note that a non-linear history at this point can create unexpected results -
What do you mean by this - is it undefined ?

Comment: It means that (1) different commands may deal differently with revsets that have multiple head or tail revisions (2) you may have to (e.g.) specify how to merge with rebase (using `--tool`) or (3) may have to think about how to filter `hg export` output to `hg import --no-commit`. It depends on what exactly you're planning on doing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [the **`histedit`** extension](https://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HisteditExtension) to achieve this. Simply type `hg histedit c561b4e977df` (where `c561b4e977df` is the hash of revision B in your example). Then type `fold` next to revisions C and D in the editor that pops up. This will collapse revisions C and D into B.

Comment: I'm trying to use this from python client api for command server so I'm not sure how I would go about "typing fold next to revisions" :) I think it would be simpler to manually walk the log output probably I just wanted to see if there was a simpler way.